# JavaScript Fetch API: how to store data in variable outside

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

Below is my code. I want to store the fetched JSON data in a variable outisde of the function scope. How can I do that?
Also, if I want to run some functions on the fetched JSON data, am I supposed to do them inside `.then()`?

```
let jsondata;

fetch('https://api.myjson.com/bins/wa759')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(myJson) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(myJson));
    jsondata = myJson;
  });

  console.log("test");
  console.log(jsondata);
```

This logs

```
> Hello (corresponding to `console.log("test");`)
> undefined (corresponding to `console.log(jsondata);`)
> (the entire JSON data)
```

Comment: Note that `fetch()` is `async` and `console.log(jasondata)` would not await for `jasondata` to be changed. That's why you get undefined.

Comment: Yes, its a good idea that whatever you want to do with jsondata, do it inside .then

Comment: You can create a custom `Promise` object and resolve it in `fetch(...).then()`